# Generating random numbers for testing a kernel density estimate

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, scipy, statistics

I have a one dimensional dataset from which I have calculated the kernel density estimate, using statsmodels and also with scipy, in python.

I want to generate a set of random numbers to see if they give me the same distribution or not.

The solution I could find so far was this :

> To draw a number x between 0 and 1 and return cdf^{-1}(x), where
>   cdf^{-1} is the inverse cumulative distribution function of 'f'.

Problem with this is, using statsmodel I am able to find the inverse cumulative distribution, but in the form of a matrix. So multiplying a number x with the matrix is not giving me a random sample from the distribution of the calculated KDE.

How can I generate a random number from the given KDE function or distribution?

EDIT:
Here is a code sample:

```
def calcKDE(data):
    #Calculating KDE
    kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(data)
    kde.fit(kernel='gau', bw='silverman')
    return kde
def generateData(data, kde):
    inverse_cdf = kde.icdf // this is a method which takes no parameters, and so is kde.cdf
    randomSet = np.random.random(1) * inverse_cdf // inverse_cdf is taken as a matrix, will also add a loop here to return 1000 random values
    return randomSet
```

Comment: A workable example would encourage people to help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @piRSquared , added sample code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inverse-transform-sampling approach looks like this:

```
from scipy.optimize import brentq
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

# fit
kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate()  # ... you already did this

# sample
u = np.random.random()

# 1-d root-finding
def func(x):
    return kde.cdf([x]) - u
sample_x = brentq(func, -99999999, 99999999)  # read brentq-docs about these constants
                                              # constants need to be sign-changing for the function
```

I recommend implementing this class-based, with a customized sample-function for better usage.

This approach is also very generic and there are much much faster approaches using additional information about the kernels in use (no inverse-transform sampling). You should find some examples by googling.

Another remark:

- [scikit-learn's kernel-density-estimation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity) brings a `sample-function` out of the box

My ordering of kde-tools from best to worst (my opinion):

- statsmodels (nice features like dependent-variables; optimization-based CV)
- scikit-learn (easy to use; sample-function; grid- and random-search based CV)
- scipy (don't like it much, but fft-based approaches for some usages -> fast)

Comment: Thanks @sascha, The problem is cdf and icdf from statsmodels are methods which do not take a parameter. Instead they return a vector/matrix. I added a code sample to the question.

Comment: @ShubhamJuneja Try my code. It will work. I use this my self! From the docs: ```cdf() Returns the cumulative distribution function evaluated at the support.``` (the *at the support* part is the important one). You might also want to skip through [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/wiki/SMEP:-redesign-of-the-KDE-modules). Also every example of plotting a statsmodels cdf will call the cdf-function with the x-array as parameters. It's the correct usage!

Comment: I am sure you are right on this, as I see the examples in the link you have provided. I tried it but it says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cdf'. Also what does "at the support" mean ? 
You can see my code [here] (https://github.com/Shubhamcl/Kernel-Density-Estimation/blob/master/Task%202.ipynb) if you'd like to :)

Comment: @ShubhamJuneja It just means ```at these given points```. And you are using the kde object in a wrong way. Don't introduce a new object ```kde1```; just create ```kde``` and use ```kde.fit```; then ```kde.cdf``` exists. In your case ```None``` will be returned and therefore your error. It looks you are not that familiar with object-oriented programming. On a closer look you are also missusing my approach above. But sadly it's quite a bit of work to explain to you whats wrong. Try to understand my example a bit better, than incorporate this. Start by checking out ```scipy.optimize```.