# conditional sampling from multivariate kernel density estimate in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

One can create  a multivariate kernel density estimate (KDE) with
scikitlearn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity)
and scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)

Both allow for random sampling from the estimated distribution. Is there a way to do conditional sampling in either of the two libraries (or any other library)?
In the 2-variable (x,y) case this would mean sample from P(x|y) (or P(y|x)), thus from a cross-section of the probability function (and that cross-section has to be rescaled to unit area under its curve).

```py
x = np.random.random(100)
y =np.random.random(100)
kde = stats.gaussian_kde([x,y])
# sampling from the whole pdf:
kde.resample()
```

I am looking for something like

```
# sampling y, conditional on x
kde.sample_conditional(x=1.5) #does not exist
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: also interested in this.

Comment: any development?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

This function samples conditionally one column based on all other columns.

```
def conditional_sample(kde, training_data, columns, values, samples = 100):
    if len(values) - len(columns) != 0:
        raise ValueError("length of columns and values should be equal")
    if training_data.shape[1] - len(columns) != 1:
        raise ValueError(f'Expected {training_data.shape[1] - 1} columns/values but {len(columns)} have be given')  
    cols_values_dict = dict(zip(columns, values))
    
    #create array to sample from
    steps = 10000  
    X_test = np.zeros((steps,training_data.shape[1]))
    for i in range(training_data.shape[1]):
        col_data = training_data.iloc[:, i]
        X_test[:, i] = np.linspace(col_data.min(),col_data.max(),steps)
    for col in columns: 
        idx_col_training_data = list(training_data.columns).index(col)
        idx_in_values_list = list(cols_values_dict.keys()).index(col)
        X_test[:, idx_col_training_data] = values[idx_in_values_list] 
        
    #compute probability of each sample
    prob_dist = np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_test))/np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_test)).sum()
    
    #sample using np.random.choice
    return X_test[np.random.choice(range(len(prob_dist)), p=prob_dist, size = (samples))]
```

Comment: nice workaround for part of the problem, but not for everything. If I understand it correctly, it works with probing the KDE with a discrete grid, which will introduce errors. Also, a KDE can actually extrapolate beyond the smallest and largest training point along an axis, which this method wont be able to do.

Comment: Indeed for more efficient conditional sampling, we need to construct the pdf i think. Sadly no implementation of pdf in sklearn.kde and no sampling implementation of sampling in statsmodels.kde

Answer (score 0):

This function works for use cases with only 1-dimensional conditions. It's built in a way that the condition doesn't need to be fulfilled exactly, but with some tolerance.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random(1000)
y = np.random.random(1000)
kde = stats.gaussian_kde([x,y])

def conditional_sample(kde, condition, precision = 0.5,  sample_size = 1000):

    block_size = int(sample_size / (2 * precision / 100))
    sample = kde.resample(block_size)

    lower_limit = np.percentile(sample[-1], stats.percentileofscore(sample[-1], condition) - precision)
    upper_limit = np.percentile(sample[-1], stats.percentileofscore(sample[-1], condition) + precision)

    conditional_sample = sample[:, (upper_limit > sample[-1]) * (sample[-1] > lower_limit)]

    return conditional_sample[0:-1]

conditional_sample(kde=kde, condition=0.6)
```

Not a universal solution but works well for my use case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

statsmodels KDEMultivariateConditional implements conditional KDEs. It can compute conditional pdf and cdf. While it has no built-in sampling method, the generic approach of inverse transform sampling can be used (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513711/generating-random-numbers-for-testing-a-kernel-density-estimate)). Note that this is probably not the most efficient way to do this. Here is an example in 2D:

```py
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density import KDEMultivariateConditional
from pylab import plt
from scipy.optimize import brentq

# generate data with some autocorrelation to make it interesting
x_train = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y_train = x_train + np.random.normal(size=1000)

# train conditional KDE
kde = KDEMultivariateConditional(endog=y_train, exog=x_train, dep_type='c', 
                                 indep_type='c', bw='normal_reference')

def cdf_conditional(x, y_target):
    # cdf of kde conditional on x, evaluated at y_target
    return kde.cdf(np.array(y_target).reshape((-1,1)), np.array(x).reshape((-1,1)))

# inverse-transform-sampling
def sample_conditional_single(x):
    # sample conditional on x
    u = np.random.random()
    # 1-d root-finding
    def func(y):
        return cdf_conditional(x, y)- u
    sample_y = brentq(func, -99999999, 99999999)  # read brentq-docs about these constants
                                                # constants need to be sign-changing for the function
    return sample_y

def sample_conditional(x, n):
    return np.array([sample_conditional_single(x) for _ in range(n)])


# now sample at 2 different x values
x1 = 0
x2 = 2
samples1 = sample_conditional(x1, 100)
samples2 = sample_conditional(x2, 100)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title("training data")
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(np.repeat(np.array(x1), len(samples1)), samples1)
plt.scatter(np.repeat(np.array(x2), len(samples2)), samples2)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('sampled conditionally')
```

[image]
[image]